# Navbar CSS not working after moving project folder

Tags: html, css

This happens whenever I try to move a project folder to a different location. This time I moved it from a team project that had a bunch of other projects into its own team project folder in TFS, the CSS for the HTML navbar page will stop working. It goes from a black bar with the page names to just this:

[image: navbar]

I haven't changed anything other than the local folder location. All folder location statements use ~/ so there shouldn't be any difference. I had to reload references so I figured that might have something to do with it, but I can't figure which one. My only solution before was to create a new project and copy the page code into it, but it really shouldn't take all that.

I'm just using the default navigation you get when you create a new .net web application. The page uses a site.master file, and the css is connected in the site.master to create the navbar:

```
Default Page:

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BudgetMaster._Default" Title="Budget Master"  %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


Site.Master:

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Site.Master.cs" Inherits="BudgetMaster.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Budget Master</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, <asp:LoginName runat="server" />!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the navbar that it is supposed to be

Comment: could you add path info or pic of door structure

Comment: Not sure what a door structure is. And path info to references, CSS, or other?

Comment: Your app will have a set route to where it's looking for the CSS file. Look for where the asset location is set to and see if that is to the correct path.

Comment: Are you missing the link and scripts for bootstrap? Or was that intentionally left out?

Comment: You may need to move your bootstrap files **with** your project for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the Bootstrap.css file got overwritten somehow, maybe when I added a new reference to it, or by nuget maybe. It didn't have most of the code that the default file that is created would have. I copied the default Boostrap.css file code of the new application into my old one, and it worked.